# Fancy Zones keyboard shortcuts to rotate windows through zones

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, tiles, powertoys

With many Linux window managers, it is not difficult to rotate the open windows through various zones with keyboard shortcuts.  With Windows 10, and even with FancyZones in PowerToys, I cannot even find an article that discusses this as a feature (current or wishlist).

For example, let's say I have four zones with two Cygwin windows and two gvim windows, and I want to rotate them all one zone clockwise.   So, if I happen to have had cyg1 topleft (tl), cyg2 tr, g1 br, and g2 bl, after the executing the shortcut, I would have c1 tr, c2 br, g1 bl, and g2 tl.   As a wishlist item, maybe just use the VIM shortcuts (maybe CTRL-WINDOWS-W could replace CTRL-W or something like that--not sure which windows keys are taken).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please clarify your request for clarification.   I have no idea why it is difficult to understand what I am asking.   Let me give it a shot.   I am asking to be able to change the positions of the windows occupying zones in Windows 10 using a keyboard shortcut.   Does that make my question more clear?   If not, please help me understand which words you do not understand.   Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the confusing part is Cygwin and GVim?   You could replace those words with MS Paint, and Google Chrome, for example.   I am just using them as examples of open Windows on my desktop.   Does that help?

Comment: lol, i just noticed that you are a bot!   (no offense)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think FancyZones can do that. Look into Autohotkey. It's possible for you to program this yourself, but it's going to take a significant amount of effort.